How can I specify the target architecture for Intellisense in a C/C++ program in VS Code?
I'm using Visual Studio Code to edit a program that will be compiled using an architecture with a different pointer width than my native one but am wanting to use Intellisense on my native computer.
For example, this
static_assert(sizeof(void*) == 4);

shows a red squiggle when void* really is of length 4 on my target architecture. How can I change this so this error message goes away?
(Note: this question is not about building for a specific architecture, rather just using Intellisense.)

Change the IntelliSense mode. In the UI this is under Extensions -> C/C++ -> C_Cpp > Default: Intelli Sense Mode.
Changing the value to msvc-x86 works properly.
This also works in settings.json
"C_Cpp.default.intelliSenseMode": "msvc-x86"

Depending on your target, you can also configure here for operating system or the specific compiler from within a few choices.
